# Can 3 people be in a LAN world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Can 3 people be in a LAN world at the same time because when the third person tried to join he couldnt see my LAN world and i watched a youtube video if 3 people can be on a LAN world and it said for the second person to type in an ip address but the second in my terms can just go into multiplayer servers and find my world but for the third person he entered my ip address and tried to join but it said that connection was timed out.

Comment: dude just try having him restart MC, and join again. That works 99.99% of the time for timeout error...

Answer (score 4):

There are no (practical) limits to how many people can play on a LAN game. You may need to check your firewall settings.

Normally, if you're all on the same LAN (I.e. you're all connected to the same network), everyone should be able to just select the LAN from the list of multiplayer worlds. However, if you can't see it, something's obviously gone wrong.

Things to check:

1. You *are* actually on the same network
2. Your firewall is not blacking the connection (you should just be able to turn off the firewall, but I would suggest only for "Private" Networks).
3. If you have Malware/Virus protection, this may also be blocking the connection. Again, turning this off should help.